# How to get a $_GET request using php

Tags: php, .htaccess

my .htaccess file contain this code :

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?username=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ profile.php?username=$1
```

for changing this url

```
http://localhost/profile.php?username=srinivas
```

to

```
http://localhost/srinivas
```

and I want to know how can i get the username with $_GET['username'] in php

Comment: I don't understand the question. If your RewriteRule works, any request for `http://localhost/srinivas` in the browser will be rewritten internally to `http://localhost/profile.php?username=srinivas`, so `$_GET['username']` will be set in profile.php. And if it doesn't work, the request won't load your PHP file at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$url = explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
foreach ($url as $val){
    $args[] = urldecode($val);
}

// $args[0] => srinivas
```

borrowed from:
[How to use $_GET parameter to make seo friendly urls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17015271/how-to-use-get-parameter-to-make-seo-friendly-urls)

Comment: If the RewriteRule works, there should be no need to do this, the PHP will see the rewritten version with a query string.